# implementing fullcalendar with angular js

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, angularjs

I am building an event scheduling app by using angular js framework and fullcalendar plugin. I tried to google and  implement different ways to make the calendar visible but it's not working. 
I have attached my snippets as follows:

**HTML:**

Planning App

```
<!-- the following 5 js files are required to use CSOM -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>

<!--StyleSheets-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.min.css" />
<link href="../Content/App.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--jQuery-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-calendar/1.0.0/calendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/LoginCtrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/calendarCtrl.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="container">


     <div ng-controller="calendarEvent">
    <div id="calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" class="span8 calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>
 </div>

</div>
```

**CalendarCtrl.js**

'use strict';

```
scheduleApp.controller('calendarEvent', ['$scope', '$compile', function ($scope, $compile) { 

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();


    /* event source that contains custom events on the scope */
    $scope.events = [
      { title: 'All Day Event', start: new Date(y, m, 1) },
      { title: 'Long Event', start: new Date(y, m, d - 5), end: new Date(y, m, d - 2) },
      { id: 999, title: 'Repeating Event', start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0), allDay: false },
      { id: 999, title: 'Repeating Event', start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0), allDay: false },
      { title: 'Birthday Party', start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0), end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30), allDay: false },
      { title: 'Click for Google', start: new Date(y, m, 28), end: new Date(y, m, 29), url: 'http://google.com/' }
    ];
    /* event source that calls a function on every view switch */


    /* Render Tooltip */
    $scope.eventRender = function (event, element, view) {
        element.attr({
            'tooltip': event.title,
            'tooltip-append-to-body': true
        });
        $compile(element)($scope);
    };

    /* config object */
    $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar: {
            height: 450,
            editable: true,
            header: {
                left: 'title',
                center: '',
                right: 'today prev,next'
            },
            eventRender: $scope.eventRender
        }   
    };
    /* event sources array*/
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];

}]);
```

**App.js**

```
var scheduleApp = angular.module('scheduleApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: Where is `ng-app="scheduleApp"`?

Comment: sorry for not putting the code properly. I have it on my index.html . <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="scheduleApp">